# inline vs. constexpr?

Tags: c++, optimization, c++11, inline, constexpr

With the new C++11 standard, when should I use the `inline` keyword over the `constexpr` keyword?  Does the `constexpr` keyword offer any additional optimization over `inline`, or does it merely assert that things must be computed at compile-time?

Why does `constexpr` work on the GCC in some cases where the call is not constant, such as calling `foo(x)` on a non-`constexpr` variable?  Is this a bug in the GCC or is it actually part of the standard?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Asserting that something can be computed at compile-time *is* a pretty strong kind of optimization.

Inlining merely removes a function call, by copy/pasting the function body into the call site. The function body still has to be executed, you just save the overhead of a function call.

But if you make the same code be evaluated at compile-time, it is *free* at runtime.

But neither `inline` nor `constexpr` are *primarily* about optimization. `inline`'s main purpose is to suppress the one-definition-rule, so that functions can be defined in headers (which is useful for templates, and incidentally, also makes the inlining optimization easier)

And `constexpr` is there because it is useful in metaprogramming, and incidentally, it may help the compiler better optimize the code, by moving more computations to compile-time.

Comment: According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7065200/636019), when `constexpr` functions are not used in a context requiring a constant expression, the compiler is not obligated to compute the expression at compile-time.

Comment: but it still specifies that the computation *can* be performed at compile-time. So as with `inline`, it's not really about optimization, but it may provide additional information that the compiler can use to optimize.

Comment: Right, I was just nitpicking about use of the word "must". :-]

Comment: @jalf I'd disagree that `inline` is not primarily about optimization. IIRC functions defined in a header file default to being inlined, though as is always the case with inline - it's merely a compiler hint. As long as you've got header guards in place then ODR isn't really relevant anyway. Willing to be educated here though :-)

Comment: @boycy wrong: a missing `inline` in a header will violate the ODR: two source files using the same non-inline function defined in the header will cause a multiple definition error when linking them together. It is exactly `inline` that fixes that.

Comment: @boycy: ODR has nothing to do with header guards. (The ODR is about multiple translation units defining the same symbol. Header guards protect against multiple definitions inside *the same* translation unit). And the compiler will inline whatever it feels like, regardless of the `inline` keyword. It can inline things that aren't marked `inline` and it is not required to inline that which you mark `inline`. So optimization-wise, the keyword doesn't really do anything.

Comment: Where optimization enters into the picture is that if you mark something `inline`, then you can make its definition visible in every translation unit where it is used without causing an ODR violation, and that makes it easier for the compiler to perform the inlining optimization. So the keyword doesn't by itself enable any new optimizations, but using it allows you to changes to how your code is structured, and those changes can enable the compiler to optimize (although a modern compiler can do optimization across translation units and then tricks like this aren't necessary either)

Comment: You mention that `inline` is useful for templates, but that isn't actually true, function templates and member functions defined inside the class are automatically treated as having the `inline` keyword before them. It's useful for free functions that will be defined in multiple translation units (usually due to being defined in a header file and included in different TUs) and avoiding the linker errors by telling the linker to discard all but one definition while linking.

Comment: The inline keyword is treated as a "suggestion" to the compiler only (https://www.cplusplus.com/articles/2LywvCM9/). Also, constexpr is "implicitly" inlined (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline). There are so many other simpler/standard ways to resolve ODR issues in C++, I personally have never considered inline to resolve this. Neither of these (first two results in my Google) websites mentions ODR.

Answer (score 6):

To quote wikipedia:

> C++0x will introduce the keyword constexpr, which allows the user to
>   guarantee that a function or object constructor is a compile-time
>   constant.

Mark functions inline if they are super short.  Mark functions as constexpr if the results are required at compile time. (Template parameters or array sizes).  I believe a function can be both if needed.

> A constant expression function or constructor can be called with
>   non-constexpr parameters. Just as a constexpr integer literal can be
>   assigned to a non-constexpr variable, so too can a constexpr function
>   be called with non-constexpr parameters, and the results stored in
>   non-constexpr variables. The keyword only allows for the possibility
>   of compile-time constancy when all members of an expression are
>   constexpr.

So, GCC is not incorrect in this.

Answer (score -4):

While `inline` says to the compiler "This function is used somewhere in this translation unit and is not public to other object files", it is likely that the compiler inserts the body of the function into the caller. `constexpr` functions say to the compiler "This function has no side effects and does not depend on preconditions other than the parameter itsself."

`constexpr` variables just say "This variable does not change and its data can be included into the code.". However it makes a difference if you define a constexpr variable in a function static or nonstatic, eg. if a `constexpr` array is nonstatic, gcc just moves the data with hardcoded `mov`-instructions onto the stack, while `static constexpr` just stores the data in the `.text`-section.

Lambda expressions without capture assigned to a variable can be constexpr other than with capture, because  without they need no memory to save the capture and they work like an empty class with overloaded `operator()` (but they can even be casted to plain function pointers with a simple unary plus: `+[]{}`).

Comment: `inline` does not imply internal linkage as you seem to be saying in your first paragraph