# constexpr overloading

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, compile-time-constant, constexpr

Related: [Function returning constexpr does not compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779013/probrem-with-constexpr-how-to-resolve-it)

I feel like constexpr is limited in usefulness in C++11 because of the inability to define two functions that would otherwise have the same signature, but have one be constexpr and the other not constexpr. In other words, it would be very helpful if I could have, for example, a constexpr std::string constructor that takes constexpr arguments only, and a non-constexpr std::string constructor for non-constexpr arguments. Another example would be a theoretically complicated function that could be made more efficient by using state. You can't easily do that with a constexpr function, so you are left with two choices: have a constexpr function that is very slow if you pass in non-constexpr arguments, or give up on constexpr entirely (or write two separate functions, but you may not know which version to call).

My question, therefore, is this:

Is it possible for a standard-compliant C++11 implementation to allow function overloading based on the arguments being constexpr, or would this require updating the standard? If it is not allowed, was it intentionally not allowed?

---

@NicolBolas: Say I have a function that maps an `enum` to a `std::string`. The most straight-forward way to do this, assuming my `enum` goes from `0` to `n - 1`, is to create an array of size `n` filled with the result.

I could create a `static constexpr char const * []` and construct a `std::string` on return (paying the cost of creating a `std::string` object every time I call the function), or I can create a `static std::string const []` and return the value I look up, paying the cost of all of the `std::string` constructors the first time I call the function. It seems like a better solution would be to create the `std::string` in memory at compile time (similar to what is done now with `char const *`), but the only way to do this would be to alert the constructor that it has `constexpr` arguments.

For a an example other than a `std::string` constructor, I think it's pretty straight-forward to find an example where, if you could ignore the requirements of `constexpr` (and thus create a non-`constexpr` function), you could create a more efficient function. Consider this thread: [constexpr question, why do these two different programs run in such a different amount of time with g++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065200/constexpr-question-why-do-these-two-different-programs-run-in-such-a-different)

If I call `fib` with a `constexpr` argument, I can't beat do better than the compiler optimizing away the function call entirely. But if I call `fib` with a non-`constexpr` argument, I may want to have it call my own version that implements things like memoization (which would require state) so I get run time similar to what would have been my compile time had I passed a `constexpr` argument.

Comment: Are you sure you actually need this? It's perfectly OK to call `constexpr` functions with non-constant arguments.

Comment: Do you have something more than "theoretical" possibilities to want this? `std::string` cannot have a constexpr constructor (except for the constructor that doesn't take parameters) because it must allocate storage for the string. Even with small-string optimization, the possibility of allocation exists. Do you have an example of a "theoretically complicated function that could be made more efficient by using state"?

Comment: @NicolBolas: I don't believe that's true, see my answer.

Comment: A quote from [this paper seems relevant to your question](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2235.pdf). `We don’t propose to make constexpr applicable to function arguments because it would be meaningless for non-inline functions (the argument would be a constant, but the function wouldn’t know which) and because it would lead to complications
of the overloading rules (can I overload on constexpr-ness? — no).`

Comment: I updated my question to respond to Nicol Bolas. It should also answer the concern brought up by Kerrek SB.

Comment: Another related issue that I've recently considered is this: it would be nice to combine assert with static_assert. In other words, if the compiler can determine that an assertion would fail (due to, for example, inlining), I would like for it to just let me know at compile-time rather than waiting until I encounter it at run-time. However, if it cannot determine it at compile time, I'd want just a regular assert. It seems like the easiest way to implement this would be something like `if (is_constexpr (value)) static_assert (condition); else assert (condition);`

Comment: `if (is_constexpr (value)) static_assert (condition); else assert (condition);` Dead code elimination does not work in such way.

Comment: @Dukales: yes, I understand, which is why I said "I would like", rather than "I do like". A lot of code would be made much simpler (and code like this possible) if we had `static if` or whatever you want to call it. Of course, even if we had `static if`, I couldn't use `static_assert` because even though I checked that `condition` is a `constexpr`, `static_assert` doesn't know that I did that and it still wouldn't compile.

Comment: I too would like this. Another example where this would be helpful is bit/population count of a bit field. Many processors include special instructions for this, so if the constexpr function is called with non-constexpr argument I'd like to use the processor instruction. But processor instructions aren't available at compile-time so I need to use another alogrithm at compile-time.

Comment: Here is a partial solution to the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39922472/6846474

Comment: Is there any new solution for this subject since C++20?

Comment: @Adam: No. I am working on a paper targeting C++23: https://github.com/davidstone/isocpp/blob/master/constexpr-parameters.md

Comment: Ok thanks, for the update!

Comment: C++20 added `std::is_constant_evaluated()` [see an answer to: Is is_constexpr possible in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299394/is-is-constexpr-possible-in-c11/67776077#67776077)

Answer (score 42):

I agree that this feature is missing - I need it too.
Example:

```
double pow(double x, int n) {
    // calculate x to the power of n
    return ...
}

static inline double pow (double x, constexpr int n) {
    // a faster implementation is possible when n is a compile time constant
    return ...
}

double myfunction (double a, int b) {
    double x, y;
    x = pow(a, b);  // call version 1 unless b becomes a compile time constant by inlining
    y = pow(a, 5),  // call version 2
    return x + y;
}
```

Now I have to do this with templates:

```
template <int n>
static inline double pow (double x) {
    // fast implementation of x ^ n, with n a compile time constant
    return ...
}
```

This is fine, but I miss the overload opportunity. If I make a library function for others to use then it is inconvenient that the user has to use different function calls depending on whether n is a compile time constant or not, and it may be difficult to predict whether the compiler has reduced n to a compile time constant or not.

Comment: This would be a good addition to the standard

Comment: Here's another example: [What is the function parameter equivalent of constexpr?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39284065) And trying the same with templates (what a mess): [Parameterization and “function template partial specialization is not allowed”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39314690).

Answer (score 10):

### **Edit:** Trick described below is not guaranteed to work anymore!

Detecting `constexpr` can't be made using overloads (like others already replied) but overloads are just one way to do it.

The typical problem is that we can't use something that can improve run-time performance (for example to call non-`constexpr` functions or to cache results) in `constexpr` function. So we may end up with two different algorithms, one less efficient but writable as `constexpr`, other optimized to run fast but not `constexpr`. Then we want compiler not to choose the `constexpr` algorithm for run-time values and vice versa.

That can be achieved by detecting `constexpr` and selecting based on it "manually" and then shortening the interface down with preprocessor macros.

First lets have two functions. In general the functions should reach same result with different algorithms. I choose two algorithms that never give same answers here just to test and to illustrate the idea:

```
#include <iostream>     // handy for test I/O
#include <type_traits>  // handy for dealing with types

// run-time "foo" is always ultimate answer
int foo_runtime(int)
{
    return 42;
}

// compile-time "foo" is factorial
constexpr int foo_compiletime(int num)
{
      return num > 1 ? foo_compiletime(num - 1) * num : 1;
}
```

Then we need a way to detect that argument is compile time constant expression. If we don't want to use compiler-specific ways like    `__builtin_constant_p` then there are ways to detect it in standard C++ as well. I'm pretty sure that following trick is invented by Johannes Schaub but I can't find the cite. Very nice and clear trick.

```
template<typename T> 
constexpr typename std::remove_reference<T>::type makeprval(T && t) 
{
    return t;
}

#define isprvalconstexpr(e) noexcept(makeprval(e))
```

The `noexcept` operator is required to work compile-time and so branching based on it will be optimized out by most compilers. So now we can write a "foo" macro that selects the algorithm based on argument's constexprness and to test it:

```
#define foo(X) (isprvalconstexpr(X)?foo_compiletime(X):foo_runtime(X))

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a = 1;
    const int b = 2;
    constexpr int c = 3;
    const int d = argc;

    std::cout << foo(a) << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo(b) << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo(c) << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo(d) << std::endl;
}
```

Expected output is:

```
42
2
6
42
```

On the few compilers that I tried it works like expected.

Comment: This seems to fall apart when you want to be able to use the result itself as a constexpr when applied to a constant though.

constexpr int e = foo(c); // fails

Comment: @EdwardKMETT It will work on case you can write `foo_runtime()` as `constexpr`. Otherwise, yes, when we need constant expression to be returned then we can't use functions that don't return it. IOW `constexpr int fooB = foo_compiletime(b);` There are no overloading in C++ based on return type.

Comment: [C++17 unfortunately closed the door for this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60586265/noexcept-behavior-of-constexpr-functions).

Comment: @AmirKirsh Strange that they removed it also for -std=C++14 mode. It smells like conspiracy to make constexpr not detectable in any way.

Comment: `constexpr` is still detectable for static storage, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60714976/2085626

Comment: That does not help since idea is not to assign to static variables but to select between efficient runtime non-constexpr (compiler intrinsic, inline assembler, trigonomertry) and potentially naive but constexpr calls depending on being in constexpr or non-constexpr context.

Answer (score 8):

It would have to be overloaded based on the result being `constexpr` or not, rather than the arguments.

A `const std::string` could store a pointer to the literal, knowing that it would never be written to (using `const_cast` to remove `const` from the `std::string` would be necessary, and that's already undefined behavior).  It'd just be necessary to store a boolean flag to inhibit freeing the buffer during destruction.

But a non-`const` string, even if initialized from `constexpr` arguments, requires dynamic allocation, because a writable copy of the argument is required, and therefore a hypothetical `constexpr` constructor should not be used.

---

From the standard (section 7.1.6.1 `[dcl.type.cv]`), modifying any object which was created `const` is undefined behavior:

> Except that any class member declared mutable (7.1.1) can be modiﬁed, any attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime (3.8) results in undefined behavior.

Comment: `const` is not a type; it is a *modifier* for a type. There is no way for your code to know that it is in a true `const std::string` instead of just a `std::string` that just so happens to be `const`-accessed right now. Without that knowledge, without being able to tell the difference, it is simply not possible to implement this optimization. That's why someone wrote an old `boost::const_string` class; because there's no way to implement it without specialized code that can detect that it is always constant.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Correct, but I don't think Ben is saying that his suggestion is possible. It would be interesting to allow the `const` modifier to be applied to constructors.

Comment: @NicolBolas: You have that backwards.  Code must never use `const_cast` to modify a `const std::string` (via pointer or reference, obviously), unless it has external knowledge that the object was not created `const`.  Modifying an object that was created `const` is already undefined behavior, adding this optimization wouldn't break anything.  I've quoted that particular section of the standard.

Comment: @BenVoigt: That doesn't change my point. There is no way for the *constructor* to know that the object it is creating is a `const` object. Without that, there is no way to store special data that `const` member functions can key off of to know that the object is really a `const` object rather than just an object that is currently being accessed as `const` (passing a value to function that takes a `const&`). A `constexpr` constructor doesn't have to create `const` objects. You're talking about a completely new kind of construct, one which doesn't exist in C++11.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I thought I appropriately covered that point in the first sentence of my answer.  But you're still missing something.  Because `const` member functions can't tell whether the object is `const`, they have to assume it is and not make modifications.  The only issue is the destructor.

Comment: @BenVoigt: This isn't about `const` member functions. It's about the constructor. The constructor must put the object in a special state of storing a literal string pointer. To do this, the constructor must be absolutely certain of three things: 1) the constructor is being called at compile time via `constexpr`. 2) the constructor's argument is a string literal. 3) the object being constructed is a `const` object. Just because the constructor is a `constexpr` constructor doesn't mean it makes a `const` object. It is not possible to detect *any* of these in C++11.

Comment: @Nicol: (1) isn't necessary.  (2) is possible using generalized literals (needed anyway to get the length).  And (3) was the whole gist of my answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt: User-defined literals cannot call any constructor that your code could not otherwise call. So if they can call a special constructor of `std::string`, then so can you. And your answer doesn't explain how the `std::string` constructor would know that it is making a `const` object.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Uh, yeah, that's the whole point.  Doing this would require overloading based on whether the object being constructed is `const`.  C++ doesn't do that.  That's my answer :)

Comment: The problem with using user-defined literals to "enforce" that you're using a string literal, is that you don't enforce anything. Yes, `"foo"_x` requires a literal, but `operator""_x(a)` doesn't.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Perhaps so, but I hardly consider the fact that a user is able to trigger UB by trying sufficiently hard a problem.  This is C++, after all.  The goal is not to prevent the user from breaking his code, it's to build a pit of success.

Comment: @BenVoigt ah, sure, I agree with that: if you go the `operator""_x` route, you do so at your own risk. Just pointing out that UDLs don't enforce anything, except out of convention.

Answer (score 8):

While there is no such thing as "constexpr overloading" in C++11, you can still use GCC/Clang `__builtin_constant_p` intrinsic. Note, that this optimization is not very useful for `double pow(double)`, because both GCC and Clang already can optimize pow for constant integral exponents, but if you write a multiprecision or vector library, then this optimization should work.

Check this example:

```
#define my_pow(a, b) (__builtin_constant_p(b) ? optimized_pow(a, b) : generic_pow(a, b))

double generic_pow(double a, double b);

__attribute__((always_inline)) inline double optimized_pow(double a, double b) {
    if (b == 0.0) return 1.0;
    if (b == 1.0) return a;
    if (b == 2.0) return a * a;
    if (b == 3.0) return a * a * a;
    if (b == 4.0) return a * a * a * a;

    return generic_pow(a, b);
}

double test(double a, double b) {
    double x = 2.0 + 2.0;
    return my_pow(a, x) + my_pow(a, b);
}
```

In this example `my_pow(a, x)` will be expanded to `a*a*a*a` (thanks to dead code elimination), and `my_pow(a, b)` will be expanded to direct `generic_pow` call without any preliminary checks.

Comment: It's a pity that `__builtin_constant_p` doesn't work on constexpr function arguments.

Answer (score 6):

### TL;DR: It is possible in C++20, with [`std::is_constant_evaluated`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constant_evaluated) in the [`<type_traits>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) header.

I came across this question with the application that [@Öö Tiib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/528720/%c3%96%c3%b6-tiib) mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35110453/12591388), in mind: I wanted to use a faster algorithm at runtime, but a slower (and `constexpr`-friendly) algorithm at compile-time.

---

Using the example in [@Öö Tiib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/528720/%c3%96%c3%b6-tiib)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35110453/12591388):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

constexpr int foo(int i) {
    if (std::is_constant_evaluated()) {
        // compile-time branch
        return (i > 1) ? foo(i - 1) * i : 1;
    } else {
        // runtime branch
        return 42;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int a = foo(1);
    const int b = foo(2);
    constexpr int c = foo(3);
    const int d = foo(argc);

    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    std::cout << d << std::endl;
}
```

gives the output

```
2
2
6
42
```

Here is a [link to the program on godbolt](https://www.godbolt.org/z/vGcvW7Pza).

Note that `foo` is indeed a legal `constexpr` function because, as the standard says, (quote copied from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/)):

> A `constexpr` function must satisfy the following requirements:
>
> - there exists at least one set of argument values such that an invocation of the function could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression (for constructors, use in a constant initializer is sufficient).

---

Note, however, that this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

constexpr int foo(int i) {
    if (std::is_constant_evaluated()) {
        // compile-time branch
        return i > 1 ? foo(i - 1) * i : 1;
    } else {
        // runtime branch
        return 42;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a = 1;
    const int b = 2;
    constexpr int c = 3;
    const int d = argc;

    std::cout << foo(a) << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo(b) << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo(c) << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo(d) << std::endl;
}
```

gives the output

```
42
42
42
42
```

[(Godbolt link)](https://www.godbolt.org/z/9G1Y5Ghn4)

I'm not entirely sure why this happens, but I suspect that it is because `std::cout`'s `operator<<` is not marked `constexpr`, so all the function calls to `foo` are happening at runtime. Interestingly, however, in Godbolt's assembly output (for x86-64 GCC 11.2), we can see the `42`s inlined. So the function is indeed evaluated at compile-time, just not in the way we would expect at first.

Answer (score 4):

The problem, as stated, feels *wrong*.

---

A `std::string`, by construction, owns the memory. If you want a simple reference to an existing buffer, you can use something akin to `llvm::StringRef`:

```
class StringRef {
public:
  constexpr StringRef(char const* d, size_t s): data(d), size(s) {}

private:
  char const* data;
  size_t size;
};
```

Of course, there is the bummer that `strlen` and all the others C functions are **not** `constexpr`. *This* feels like a defect of the Standard (think about all the maths functions...).

---

As for state, you can (a bit), as long as you understand *how* to store it. Remember that loops are equivalent to recursions ? Well, likewise, you can "store" state by passing it as argument to a helper function.

```
// potentially unsafe (non-limited)
constexpr int length(char const* c) {
  return *c == '\0' ? 0 : 1 + length(c+1);
}

// OR a safer version
constexpr int length_helper(char const* c, unsigned limit) {
  return *c == '\0' or limit <= 0 ? 0 : 1 + length_helper(c+1, limit-1);
}

constexpr int length256(char const* c) { return length_helper(c, 256); }
```

Of course, this form of this state is somewhat limited (you cannot use complicated constructs) and that is a limitation of `constexpr`. But it's already a *huge* leap forward. Going further would mean going deeper into purity (which is hardly possible in C++).

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible for a standard-compliant C++11 implementation to allow function overloading based on the arguments being constexpr, or would this require updating the standard? If it is not allowed, was it intentionally not allowed?

If the standard doesn't say you can do something, then allowing someone to do it would be non-standard behavior. And therefore, a compiler that allowed it would be implementing a language extension.

That's not necessarily a bad thing, after all. But it wouldn't be compliant C++11.

We can only guess at the intentions of the standards committee. They may have deliberately not allowed it, or it may have been something of an oversight. The fact is that the standard doesn't overloading is allowed, therefore it isn't.

Comment: SFINAE can be used to implement overloading with rules different from the default. Using a function argument as a template parameter in the signature may be a legal way to disable a function for non-constexpr arguments. Or maybe not. I'm not going to look it up because, as Ben explains, the result would be useless anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Another option to detect compile-time compilation using SFINAE: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3a2c11bcccdb5bf

```
template<typename T>
auto f(const T&)
{
  return 1;
}

constexpr auto f(int)
{
  return 2;
}



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template<typename T, int=f(T{})>
constexpr bool is_f_constexpr_for(int) {return true;}

template<typename...>
constexpr bool is_f_constexpr_for(...) {return false;}



template<typename T>
auto g(const T& t)
{
  if constexpr (is_f_constexpr_for<T>(0))
  {

  }
  else
  {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to identify whether a given ***static storage*** variable is a constant expression, using *an approach [proposed by Richard Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50169108/2085626)* based on narrowing conversion rules.

We can assign to an `unsigned int` a `consexpr` **non-negative** `int` **without narrowing**:

```
unsigned int u {std::max(0, -3)}; // compiles, max is constexpr
```

However, we cannot do the above if we use a variable:

```
int a = 3;
unsigned int u {std::max(0, a)}; // compilation error, narrowing int to unsigned int
```

To identify whether a given `int reference` is const expression, we can test whether it can be assigned to an `unsigned int` **without narrowing** with either its positive *or* negative value. This should be possible for any `int` which value is known at compile time, i.e. can be considered as a constant expression.

```
template<const int& p> std::true_type
    is_constexpr_impl(decltype((unsigned int){std::max(-p, p)}));
template<const int& p> std::false_type
    is_constexpr_impl(...);
template<const int& p> using is_constexpr =
    decltype(is_constexpr_impl<p>(0));
```

Now we can have different implementations for runtime and compile time with the macro approach:

```
int foo_runtime(int num) {
    return num;
}

constexpr int foo_compiletime(int num) {
      return num + 1;
}

#define foo(X) (is_constexpr<X>()?foo_compiletime(X):foo_runtime(X))
```

And as said, [it will mimic an overload for const expression](https://godbolt.org/z/mC2Fn4):

```
int main() {
    static int a = 3;
    static const int b = 42; // considered constexpr
    static const int c = foo_runtime(42); // not constexpr
    static constexpr int d = 4;
    static constexpr int e = -2;
    static int f = 0;
    static const int g = 0; // considered constexpr

    std::cout << foo(a) << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo(b) << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo(c) << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo(d) << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo(e) << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo(f) << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo(g) << std::endl;
}
```

---

Above is nice, though not very useful as it is limited to ***static storage*** variables. But it does present overloading based on `constexpr`.

---

Another approach to achieve the same, without depending on narrowing conversion, [can be](https://godbolt.org/z/w5x9fh):

```
template<const int& p> std::true_type
    is_constexpr_impl(std::array<int, std::max(p, -p)>);
template<const int& p> std::false_type
    is_constexpr_impl(...);
template<const int& p> using is_constexpr = 
    decltype(is_constexpr_impl<p>(0));
```

The use of `std::array` above replaces using simple c-array, [which doesn't work well for gcc with this approach](https://godbolt.org/z/Gb4MQ3).

---

Or another one - again, without relying on narrowing rules - [that also works fine](https://godbolt.org/z/2UgSar):

```
template<const int& p, typename T = void>
struct is_constexpr: std::false_type {};

template<const int& p>
struct is_constexpr<p, std::void_t<int[std::max(p,-p)+1]>>: std::true_type {};
```

---

Note that ***if we would try to achieve the same*** with a [more simple approach](https://godbolt.org/z/XPqjJj):

```
template<typename T>
struct is_constexpr: std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_constexpr<const T>: std::true_type {};

#define foo(X) (is_constexpr<decltype(X)>()?foo_compiletime(X):foo_runtime(X))
```

**We would not achieve our goal for this line:**

```
static const int c = foo_runtime(42); // const but not constexpr
```

Comment: Can you explain which version is the "bottom line" here? i.e. what's recommended for use?

Comment: @einpoklum what is your required usage?

Comment: Nothing at the moment, just curious.

Comment: @einpoklum the idea was to present that there can be different approaches checking for `is_constexpr`, i.e. using: (1) narrowing rules, (2) template non-type parameter, (3) array size. Though, all these options work only for static storage variables as they are all based on passing the variable being checked as a template parameter by reference.

Comment: A simpler implementation than `std::max(x, -x)` that works with all types (and `INT_MIN`) would be `(void(expr), 0)`. It always produces the value `0`, but is only a constant expression if the first argument to the comma operator is a constant expression.