# Convert code to constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11, containers, c++14, constexpr

What are the general tips to convert a code to be a `constexpr`? Say, there is an algorithm for some geometrical transormation of (input) geometrical figure. Input and output differs by nature and size and depends from each other non-trivially. Currently it implemented as a class, which currently uses `std::map` and `std::vector` (without loss of generality).

What is a way to refactor code, that uses dynamic memory, to gain code, which matches the requirements for constant expressions?

I can imagine some combination of `constexpr`-compatible containers and `constexpr`-compatible implementation of ["stack allocator"](https://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.html) (for big enough storage) for each `value_type` of containers used. But there is a problem: I never met such a containers. But maybe there are another ways?

Comment: this is too general.

Comment: @DavidHaim Where is a place for such general questions? I move the question to that place. Is there SO-like place?

Comment: Do you have something which *should* (or could) be a compile-time expression or value? Do you have a function which meets all the requirements for a [`constexpr` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)? Then you could make the expression, variable or function `constexpr`. And it doesn't hurt if you make something `constexpr` if that something really isn't or can't be a compile-time constant, it just implies `const` in that case.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Currently don't, but want to. I don't use `reinterpret_cast`, placement `new` and other weird things. But I want to write a `constexpr` code, which is similar to its non-`constexpr` counterpart from a reader's point of view. I want to establish some kind of bijection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For most algorithms and utility classes (`std::bitset`, `std::array`, etc.) in the standard library, **you can simply add the `constexpr` specifier everywhere** and try and store the result in a `constexpr` variable. **Most likely, this will compile and run successfully**. See also [**this Q&A**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18052208/819272).

What will typically stop such code from compiling is one of the current language restrictions on compile-time constant expressions, such as (look at **5.20 Constant expressions [expr.const]** for the full list)

- dynamic memory allocation (inside `std::inplace_merge` e.g.)
- virtual functions (in `<iostream>`)
- lambda expressions (proposed and accepted for standardization in [**N4487**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4487.pdf))
- `reinterpret_cast`
- `goto` (proposed but rejected for standardization in [**N4472**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4472.html))

For each restriction, there are ways to get around it

- The alternative to the system supported dynamic memory allocation
  through `new`/`delete` is to write your own memory pool in a large
  global `constexpr` array.
- The alternative to virtual functions is to store an array of function
  pointers (that call `constexpr` functions) and dispatch them through
  a `switch` statement.
- The alternative to lambdas is to write your own function objects with
  a `constexpr operator()`.
- The alternative to `reinterpret_cast` is to use a [**`constexpr`
  variant**](https://github.com/eggs-cpp/variant) (with a `union` underneath it).
- The alternative to `goto` is to write more structured code using
  regular loops and branches.

In all cases, **you will lose the syntactic niceties** of being able to call `new`/`delete` or implicit dynamic dispatching. You will have to manually allocate/deallocate your memory and to manually select your function pointer.

Note that even though large parts of the standard library could be made `constexpr` even with the current C++14/17 language, they currently are not. Moreover, **standard library implementors are forbidden from adding extra `constexpr` functionality** (in contrast from being allowed to offer stronger `noexcept` support).

Complain to your vendors or the C++ committee if you think there should be more or easier `constexpr` support (both in the language and the standard library).

Comment: Alternative to `reinterpret_cast` from raw storage is to use `constexpr` variant (for example [this](https://github.com/eggs-cpp/variant)).