# Why is std::tie not marked constexpr for C++14?

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, constexpr, c++14

This is a follow-up question to my previous questions ["Which parts of the C++14 Standard Library could be and which parts will be made `constexpr`?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18052208/819272) and ["Guidelines to do `constexpr` operator-overloading?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17744842/819272)

In the runtime world, a [nice idiom to overload `operator<` for a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6218812/819272) of several data members, is to use `std::tie` to convert a struct into a `std::tuple` and piggy-back on its `operator<` which does the Right Thing™ (lexicographic comparison on the various members).

In C++14, many parts of `std::tuple` are made `constexpr`, in particular `make_tuple`, `std::get` and the earlier mentioned `operator<`. However, it appears that the seemingly related `std::tie` is not marked `constexpr`. This is rather annoying because it makes defining user-defined literal types that can be compared at compile-time more verbose than necessary.

**Question: are there any technical reasons for which `std::tie` is not marked `constexpr` for C++14?**

**UPDATE**: [LWG issue 2301](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/lwg/issue2301), [implemented in libc++](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20140224/099936.html) and [libstdc++ bug 65978](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65978)

**UPDATE2**: fixed by @JonathanWakely a little over 3 hours after submitting the libstdc++ bug report!

Comment: Since it only creates a tuple of references, there can really be no reason not to mark it `constexpr`.

Comment: @Xeo I wish everything was constexpr by default, and the compiler would just give a warning whenever it can't evaluate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In any case where it would utilize `constexpr`ness, `make_tuple` should behave exactly the same as `tie` except that notionally `tie` would add an extra level of unneeded indirection from the references. Thus there's no need for `tie` to be `constexpr` since `make_tuple` would serve that purpose.

Comment: `make_tuple` is indeed a workaround at compile-time, but now whenever I drop down to the runtime world, wouldn't `operator<` be making 2 extra copies? And since functions don't overload on constexpr, having 2 overloads is no option either.

Comment: FWIW, you can `std::make_tuple(std::cref(args)...)` the whole thing, but eeeeh.

Comment: @TemplateRex Once you drop down to runtime you're no longer in `constexpr` land so you use `tie` instead (unless I miss something here).

Comment: but the whole point of the relaxed C++14-style `constexpr` is to *gracefully* drop to runtime land, not to incur needless copies. This was the main pain point in C++11, that needlessly forced you into recursion and `?` operator style coding. Now we have `for`, `switch` and `if`, and can write algorithms (if only lambdas were `constexpr`).

Comment: @Xeo Eeeh indeed. I think I'll try a simple definition `private::tie` to do what you are proposing, or simply copy-paste the `std::tie`, rename it and mark it `constexpr`.

Comment: @MarkB, you don't want to have to implement a type's `operator<` twice, one way when using it in a (possibly) constant expression context and another way (with a different name) to use elsewhere, that's just annoying.

Comment: @JonathanWakely will this get fixed or should I submit a DR?

Comment: @TemplateRex, I don't know of any existing DR or national body comment, so please submit one

Comment: @JonathanWakely could you point me to the appropriate channels, please?

Comment: @JonathanWakely thanks, I have submitted a DR, almost identical in substance as Issue 2275 where the same point was observed about `forward_as_tuple`.