# Implicitly convert number to integral const

Tags: c++, templates, implicit-conversion

Suppose I have the function:

```
template<size_t N>
void foo(std::integral_constant<size_t,N>);
```

Right now to use it I do this:

```
constexpr size_t myNum = 12;
foo(std::integral_constant<size_t,myNum>());
```

But I would like a way to use it like this:

```
constexpr size_t myNum = 12;
foo(myNum);
```

Is there any way to implicitly convert a number to the corresponding `std::integral_constant`?

Comment: For literals, you can have a `_c` or similar user-defined literal. However, that won't work for a non-literal.

Comment: @chris How would that work?

Comment: There's lots of [info](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) on the feature. Boost.Hana has one, too. Using it would be a simple case of `foo(12_c)`.

Comment: Not sure why you would do that. The whole point is that `std::integral_constant` are a type. They are not supposed to be objects. So how do you pass a type to a function (templates). But why would you do that when you can use integer as template parameter.

Comment: @LokiAstari, I'd say Hana has made a good case for turning types into objects. `tuple[5_c] = "foo";` and `filter(tuple, [](auto type) { return is_pointer(type); })` are two examples.

Comment: @chris: Who is Hana. And I have no idea what you are trying to explain or why that is better than (I have no idea what it is replacing).

Comment: @chris You should post an answer....that is awesome.....

Comment: Just found this by searching google https://boostorg.github.io/hana/index.html#tutorial-integral

Comment: @DarthRubik, I don't feel it's comprehensive enough. It covers one specific scenario and says nothing about the rest.

Comment: @LokiAstari, As Darth found (and as I had expanded above), I meant Boost.Hana, which is officially in 1.61.0. It gives a pretty good advantage in the opening of Darth's link: *Furthermore, we can now perform compile-time arithmetic using the same syntax as that of normal C++.* I suppose it *was* Louis Dionne, the author, making the case, though.

Comment: @LokiAstari Wanting to call an operator<< or operator>> is a case where an explicit integer template parameter for the number of bits to shift is unavailable, but the compiler can infer that template parameter if the operand is std::integral_constant. This can be useful because shifts with immediate operands can be more efficient then run-time variable operands. e.g. int x = a << 3_c

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that true implicit conversion is not possible. However, you can use macros and compile-time constant detection (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13305072/6846474) to emulate the desired syntax along with "[constexpr overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936549/constexpr-overloading)".

Here is my C++14 implementation of the trick:

```
#include <iostream>

// Compile-time constant detection for C++11 and newer
template <typename T> 
constexpr typename std::remove_reference<T>::type makeprval(T && t) 
{
    return t;
}

#define is_const(X) noexcept(makeprval(X)) // broken in Clang
//#define is_const(X) __builtin_constant_p(X) // non-standard but works in GCC and Clang

template <bool c>
struct const_var_impl {
    template <typename CFn, typename VFn>
    static inline auto resolve_branch(CFn cf, VFn vf) {}
};

template <>
struct const_var_impl<true> {
    template <typename CFn, typename VFn>
    static inline auto resolve_branch(CFn cf, VFn vf) {
        return cf();
    }
};

template <>
struct const_var_impl<false> {
    template <typename CFn, typename VFn>
    static inline auto resolve_branch(CFn cf, VFn vf) {
        return vf();
    }
};

#define const_var_branch(X, F) \
    const_var_impl<is_const(X)>::resolve_branch( \
        [&]() { \
            constexpr auto _x_val = is_const(X) ? X : 0; \
            return F(std::integral_constant<decltype(X), _x_val>{}); \
        }, \
        [&]() { \
            return F(X); \
        } \
    )

template <typename T, T c>
void fn_impl(std::integral_constant<T, c> c_arg) {
    std::cout << "Constant " << c_arg << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void fn_impl(T v_arg) {
    std::cout << "Variable " << v_arg << std::endl;
}

#define fn(X) const_var_branch(X, fn_impl)

int main(void) {
    int n = 2;

    fn(1); // Prints "Constant 1"
    fn(n); // Prints "Variable 2"
    return 0;
}
```

You have to use a macro because only a constant literal or a constexpr expression is treated as compile-time constant. Constant propagation cannot be detected as far as I know.

So, we have two overloads of `fn_impl`. The compile-time and the runtime implementation.

The main idea is to use two lambda functions, one of which will be called depending on the value of `is_const(X)`. Each lambda calls one of the two overloads after explicitly converting our constant/variable `X` to the correct type. The correct lambda is going to be called via a template specialization of `const_var_impl`.

The tricky part was to make this work without compiler errors. You somehow have to take the `X` from the `const_var_branch` macro and try to create `integral_constant` from it which is not possible if `X` is non-constant.

Luckily, we can do this:

```
constexpr auto _x_val = is_const(X) ? X : 0;
```

Now the code is always valid. If `X` is constant, we get its value and instantiate `integral_constant` with it. Otherwise we end up with zero which is fine, because the lambda with compile-time implementation is not going to be called anyway.

The obvious limitation of this approach is that for each function we want to overload, we have to create a macro and use that for the calls. This is of course not practical if we wanted to call methods or functions within namespaces.

To solve this issue, we could create a similar macro that wraps the function argument only:

```
#define var_or_const(X) const_var_branch(X, [](auto && x) {return x;})
```

This macro returns either the `X` of some integral type `T` or an instance of `std::integral_constant<T, X>`.

Then we would use it on `fn_impl` directly:

```
fn_impl(var_or_const(n));
```

This is however still far from implicit.

Comment: I'm almost certain that your `noexcept` trick to detect constexpr is broken on clang; did you test with clang? I asked a similar question about this and found that clang has had this bug (not marking constexpr expressions noexcept) for 3 years, as of maybe 6 months ago. Not sure if it's been fixed more recently.

Comment: You're right. It is broken. However, I just found out that the non-standard __builtin_constant_p (which is commented out in the code) works in gcc and clang too. I'm gonna edit the answer.

Answer (score -1):

It's not exactly the syntax you wanted, but:

```
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

template<int T>
void foo(){} // you can make an integral_constant using T
int main(){
    constexpr int five=5;
  foo<five>();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/g/lt0VKD

`std::integral_type` has no constructor - so everything has to be known at compile time and different input parameters (not used for type deduction) don't cause code generation.

Comment: Actually it has a default constructor

Comment: You're correct, I meant none that takes a value.. because there's only one value it could possibly take which means it's not actually needed

Comment: @DarthRubik: But why would you need the object?

Comment: @xaxxon: The comment was at Darth's original comment. Sorry.

Comment: @LokiAstari  Lets just say being obsessed with `constexpr` and template meta programming creates problems like this