# What is the function parameter equivalent of constexpr?

Tags: c++11, clang, constexpr

We are trying to speedup some code under Clang and Visual C++ (GCC and ICC is OK). We *thought* we could use `constexpr` to tell Clang a value is a compile time constant but its causing a compile error:

```
$ clang++ -g2 -O3 -std=c++11 test.cxx -o test.exe
test.cxx:11:46: error: function parameter cannot be constexpr
unsigned int RightRotate(unsigned int value, constexpr unsigned int rotate)
                                             ^
1 error generated.
```

Here is the reduced case:

```cxx
$ cat test.cxx
#include <iostream>

unsigned int RightRotate(unsigned int value, constexpr unsigned int rotate);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::cout << "Rotated: " << RightRotate(argc, 2) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

unsigned int RightRotate(unsigned int value, constexpr unsigned int rotate)
{
  // x = value; y = rotate
  __asm__ ("rorl %1, %0" : "+mq" (value) : "I" ((unsigned char)rotate));
  return value;
}
```

GCC and ICC will do the right thing. They recognize a value like `2` in the expression `RightRotate(argc, 2)` cannot change under the laws of the physical universe as we know them, and it will treat `2` as a compile time constant and propagate it into the assembly code.

If we remove the `constexpr`, then Clang and VC++ aseembles the function into a `rotate REGISTER`, which is up to 3x slower than a `rotate IMMEDIATE`.

How do we tell Clang the function parameter `rotate` is a compile time constant, and it should be assembled into a `rotate IMMEDIATE` rather than a `rotate REGISTER`?

Comment: If the value is a compile time constant, then presumably the compiler needs to generate a version of the function for each value of that constant. That sounds to me like a template.

Comment: @Tim - I tried to parameterize and specialize, but it results in *`function template partial specialization is not allowed`*. What alternate reality or universe is Clang and the C++ committee operating in?

Comment: @Tim - Here's the follow-up question: [Parameterization and and “function template partial specialization is not allowed”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39314690)

Answer (score 5):

You could use non-type template arguments for this:

```
template <unsigned int rotate> RightRotate(unsigned int value) {
     ...
}
```

You'd then invoke it as

```
RightRotate<137>(argument); // rotate is 137 here
```

Comment: Thanks @templatetypedef. We've got some other constraints that are getting in the way of a full blown template at the moment. I've been thinking seriously about adding a new set of functions so that we can use templates to achieve the good code generation....

Comment: Here's the follow-up question: [Parameterization and and “function template partial specialization is not allowed”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39314690)

Comment: If RightRotate were a constructor instead, or a function with deduced template arguments (ADL), you can use `template<unsigned int UI> using UIConst = integral_constant<unsigned int, UI>;` in calls like `RightRotate(UIConst<rotate>{})`. (If you want to deduce the type from a constructor of that style (ADL) e.g. `auto rr = RightRotate(UIConst<90>{});` where `rr` is deduced to be an instance of struct `RightRotate<90>` you will unfortunately need a helper function in the style of `make_tuple`.) Hope this helps someone!