# Static assert that passes if expression is not known at compile time

Tags: c++, constexpr

I want to implement `my_static_assert` that slightly differs from c++17 single-parametric `static_assert`: if condition inside `my_static_assert` **is not known** at compile time, it should **pass**.

The second `my_static_assert` in the following example should pass but if I would use `static_assert` it will fail.

```
#include <iostream>

int x, y;
constexpr int f1() { return 0; }
constexpr int f2() { return 0; }
int f3() { return x; }
int f4() { return y; }
constexpr int sum(int a, int b) { return a + b; }

int main() {
    std::cin >> x >> y;

    // it should fail 
    my_static_assert(sum(sum(f1(), f2()), sum(f1(), f1())) != 0);

    // it should pass
    my_static_assert(sum(sum(f1(), f2()), sum(f4(), sum(f3(), f1()))) != 0);
}
```

If you want to know why this question arised:

I am building expressions using leaf functions f1,f2,f3,f4 and operations on the expression nodes: sum,mul,div,sub. Leafs that are known at compile time contain value that is always 0.

I am trying to check that my expressions contain at least one element that is not known at compile time.

Comment: I don't think this is possible :(

Comment: Looks like there are a couple options in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936549/constexpr-overloading).  Not really sure if this should be a dupe though.

Comment: This is similar to `is_constexpr`. There is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299394/is-is-constexpr-possible-in-c11) but it concluded there is no standards-compliant way to do it

Answer (score 7):

If you are willing to commit to a compiler with GNU extensions, it's possible. So be warned.

It takes two overloads and a helper macro:

```
template<std::size_t N>
constexpr void assert_helpr(int(&)[N]) = delete;

void assert_helpr(...) {}

#define my_static_assert(...) do {               \
    __extension__ int _tmp [(__VA_ARGS__) + 1];  \
    assert_helpr(_tmp);                          \
} while(0)
```

It works as follows:

1. The macro grabs your token soup and treats it like an integral expression. +1 is to avoid pathological zero cases.
2. If the expression is a constant expression, we get a standard array. Otherwise we get a VLA.
3. Now we call one of two overloaded functions. Overload resolution will always choose a c var-arg function last. If what we got was a regular array, the first, deleted overload is chosen, and the assertion fails.
4. If we got a VLA, the second overload is chosen and the assertion passes.

I haven't tested it thoroughly, but it seems to work on both Clang and GCC. [See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f203b95ea12bd138).

---

[@Artyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5754656/artyer) was kind enough to share a solution based on this approach on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/IaP0cr).

Here's a [reduction](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1f35d8172f2cdbd) of that code to this problem:

```
template<std::size_t N>
constexpr std::false_type assert_helpr(int(&)[N]);
constexpr std::true_type  assert_helpr(...);

#define my_static_assert(...) do {                               \
    __extension__ int _tmp[(__VA_ARGS__) + 1];                   \
    static_assert(decltype(assert_helpr(_tmp)){}, #__VA_ARGS__); \
} while(0)
```

Same use of overloading, except this time we grab an actual result type from the call via `decltype`, and proceed to create a true compile time Boolean constant out of it.

This allows direct use of `static_assert`, and as a nice to have feature, we can pass it the stringified token soup to get an indication in the error of the expression that failed.

Comment: Here's a version heavily inspired by this one that uses a `static_assert` so there is a message: https://godbolt.org/z/IaP0cr . It also has some of the issues (The difference between "`constexpr`" and "compile time constant")

Comment: @Artyer - Not bad at all!